# Start of NKAssetdownload delayed with iOS5.1 update for newstand app

Tags: ios5.1, newsstand-kit

I have a published application for ipad which is a newstand app.

Ever since the 5.1 iOs update when I try to download any issues using 
NKAssetDownload I get a very long delay until the update starts.

I get no error message or anything it just takes a really long time(5-10mins)
for the download to start.

After the download starts it proceeds normally and finishes without any further 
delay or errors.

If I could have any suggestions on what the problem might be or how I could 
possibly debug it I would really appreciate it as this is a live app and 
customers are starting to go crazy.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommend that you download an issue as one file. If you download as multiple files (e.g. one file per page) there will be a delay before the update notification appears. This is because the download progress indication that is sent to the app is per file. If you are downloading several files at once the time taken to get significant (notifiable) progress on one file is extended due to the bandwidth being shared.

Comment: It actually is just one file per issue I am downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, too.
I ended up using NKAssetDownload only for the newsstand push background download. For normal in-app downloads that run in foreground, I use a URLConnection.
NKAssetDownload doesn't seem to be made for foreground use, as it is not reliable enough for the user to wait for it to finish.

Comment: I have been developing Newsstand apps for over 12 months: downloading in the foreground works very well but can be slower than downloading directly via an NSURLConnection. With NK, the user can request a download and then background/ terminate the app and the download will continue. In this case it could be said that the user doesn't have to "wait" using Newsstand but does using NSURLConnection. It's a choice you have to make. One problem with sometimes downloading using NK and sometimes not is that the issues will be stored in two different places and your software will have to deal with this